Can't get started with Tao Ex 3.6.6 regarding cardinality of power sets.
I can't seem to get started with Ex 3.6.6. from Tao's Analysis I 4th ed:

Exercise 3.6.6 (first part)
Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be sets. Show that the sets $(A^B)^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$ have equal cardinality by constructing an explicit bijection between the two sets.

Note: Tao defines the power set as the set $A^B$ as the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$.
Question:
Despite thinking about this for 2 weeks, my brain just can't find a way to intuitively find an objection between the two sets, before I even show it is a bijection (surjective, injective).
Discussion
With the previous exercise 3.6.5 we're asked to show the sets $A \times B$ and $B \times A$ have equal cardinality. My brain starts with the intuition that the elements of $A \times B$ are $(a,b)$ where necessarily $a \in A, b \in B$. The intuition is that for each $(a,b)$ there is a unique $(b,a)$. I can then make the leap to say this is in $B \times A$ by definition of cartesian products.
Once I have the intuition I can then do the working to show injectivity and surjectivity.
For this Ex 3.6.6 I can't even get an intuitive foothold to get started.
I also note that the usual online solutions websites that I use when stuck don't answer this question. Is it particularly difficult?

See currying.

You've asked about intuition a few times in the comments to the answers -- first try to solve the problem for a concrete case. For example, A = {1, 2, 3}; B = {table, chair}; C = {blue, red}. Actually take the time to list out the entire contents of the two sets in question. The way you get intuition is to do a sufficient number of specific cases to be able to generalize more abstractly.

excellent idea @fish

What can we do with some $f\in (A^B)^C$? Well for example we can evaluate it, we can take $f(c)$ which is an element of $A^B$ so a function again. And so we can evaluate it one more time, we can take $f(c)(b)$ which is an element of $A$.
With this you can literally transform such $f$ into $g\in A^{B\times C}$ by defining $g(b,c):= f(c)(b)$. In other words this defines a function
$$\Theta:(A^B)^C\to A^{B\times C}$$
$$\Theta(f)(b,c):= f(c)(b)$$
On the other hand given $g\in A^{B\times C}$ we first define $f_c\in A^B$ via $f_c(b)=g(b,c)$ and then $f\in (A^B)^C$ via $f(c)=f_c$. In other words this gives us a function
$$\Psi:A^{B\times C}\to (A^B)^C$$
$$\Psi(f)(c)(b):=f(b,c)$$
The only thing you need to show now is that $\Theta$ and $\Psi$ are inverses of each other. And therefore bijections. Which is rather straightforward if you look closely at how these are defined.

Thanks @freakish your answers explains the thought process which I appreciate. What I am stuck is assuring myself that any choice of $f \in (A^B)^C$ and $g \in A^{B \times C)$ will conform to our requirements that $h(f)=g$ is a bijection. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

@Penelope It isn't "any" choice. The $g$ function is precisely constructed out of $f$, and vice versa (in the second scenario). We don't chose anything here, we build. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Thanks @freakish I will have to print this out and read it several times tomorrow to see if I can understand it. Thanks again.

Others have provided the formal argument. Let me add a down-to-earth reasoning.
A function $f \in A^{B\times C}$ is like an office cabinet with many drawers, labelled by all possible pairs $(b,c)$ with $b\in B, c\in C$. Given any such a pair, you can open the associated drawer and find a value $f(b,c) \in A$ inside.
A function $g \in (A^B)^C$ is like an office cabinet with fewer drawers, but larger ones. They are only labelled by $c\in C$. Given any such $c$, opening the associated drawer reveals many folders inside, each one labelled by $b\in B$. In each folder, there is a value $g(c)(b) \in A$ inside.
Now think about how the information stored in cabinet $f$ can be moved to cabinet $g$, or vice versa, with no loss of information. This is the bijection $A^{B\times C} \cong (A^B)^C$.

this is brilliant - thank you so much!

The bijection is the following:
$$\Psi\colon A^{B\times C}\to (A^B)^C,\qquad  (f\colon B\times C \to A) \mapsto \Psi(f):=(C\to A^B,\quad c\mapsto (B\to A, f(\cdot ,c)).$$
Can you prove that this is a bijection?

What's the intuition that led you to this answer? The intuition is the bit I'd like to develop or understand.

There is no intuition here, it is just the most natural map that you can define to obtain what do you expect, namely that A^{B\times C} and (A^B)^C have the same cardinality. MAtbe a way to get this intuition is to think first of all to A,B, C being finite sets.

@FedericoFallucca I think what you're describing is the definition of intuition.

You're right  :)
